# How to clicked button id and make change on div which has the same id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using https://github.com/daneden/animate.css this css class to animate the boxes in grid.If a user clicks on "Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion" then the box with fahtocel id moves.Same for second box , It works well what I have written but Itmakes no sense to write javascript function for each box, Is there a way to get id of clicked div and relate it with the box which has to move in one function.

```js
function bounce() {
  $("#fahtocel").addClass("animated bounce");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#fahtocel").removeClass("animated");
    $("#fahtocel").removeClass("bounce");
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(genQuote(), 5000);
}

function bounce2() {
  $("#box2").addClass("animated bounce");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#box2").removeClass("animated");
    $("#box2").removeClass("bounce");
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(genQuote(), 5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="bounce()">Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="bounce2()">Box 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 box" id="fahtocel">
    <div class="inner"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 box" id="box2">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `Is there a way to get id of clicked div` - yes; `and relate it with the box which has to move` - sure, but i don't get how to determine which `div` needs to be moved

Comment: Using id not. using classes you can. Remember that Id are unique identifiers and can only be referenced to a single object

Comment: Alternatively you can get the box id as a parameter and work with it.

Comment: First li should first div and second li should move second div.

Comment: If I give a class to first li "first header" and related div "first box" and with the parent class first can I determine in javascript function which box is going to move?

Comment: You're making it too hard on yourself -- you can just pass the ID for the DIVs you want to change as a parameter in the function. `onclick="bounce('fahtocel')"` and `function bounce( elementID ){ ... }` and to reference it in jQuery `$('#' + elementID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the ID (as a string/text) for the DIVs you want to change as a parameter to the function.

HTML

`onclick="bounce('fahtocel')"`

JavaScript

`function bounce( elementID ){ ... }`

jQuery

`$('#' + elementID)`

As an aside, I also turned your first DIVs into buttons -- not something that you have to do, its just nice to use buttons for things that need to be clicked instead of shoe-horning that functionality into a DIV.

```js
function bounce( elementID ) {
  var target = $('#' + elementID );
  target.addClass("animated bounce");

  setTimeout(function() {
    target.removeClass("animated");
    target.removeClass("bounce");
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    genQuote( elementID );
  }, 5000);
}

function genQuote( elementID ){
  // you can pass the string for the ID to another
  // function. it's just like a variable, but you
  // need to make sure your function will send and
  // receive them as nessecary.
  $('#' + elementID ).html( new Date() );
  // this is just randomly putting in the current date
  // and time to show an update.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button onclick="bounce('fahtocel')">Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="bounce('box2')">Box 2</button>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 box" id="fahtocel">
    <div class="inner"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 box" id="box2">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes exactly this was what I was looking, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can make this function, and call it twice when needed:

```
function bounceBox($box){

   $box.addClass("animated bounce");

   setTimeout(function(){
      $box.removeClass("animated");
      $box.removeClass("bounce");
   }, 1000);
   setTimeout(genQuote, 5000);
}

bounceBox($('#fahtocel'));
bounceBox($('#box2'));
```

There is probably more that can be done, but you didn't show the code for it.

Comment: it would be better only getting the id name in the parameter. That way is simpler when calling the function from the html

Comment: `setTimeout(genQuote(), 5000);` should be `setTimeout(genQuote, 5000);` too

Comment: <div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="bounceBox($("#fahtocel")))"> I tried but It didnt work how should I use it in onclick correctly?

Comment: Use single quotes: onclick="bounceBox($('#fahtocel')))"

Comment: just pass the ID name (`'fahtocel'`), not the jQuery equivalent -- In this way, HTML cannot send the element to JavaScript.  You'll need to use jQuery to select your element(s)